# DbSet.Add to ignore properties that is not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using EFCore, the model has a table with a foreign key constraints, it refers to another table, but this column is **nullable**. Models like this:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    ... // other fields
}
public class OrderCode
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

Order o = new Order { Amount = 1 }; // Code is not set and default NULL in DB
orders.Add(o);
db.SaveChanges(); // failure
```

So for some case the `Code` is empty and it is default `NULL` in database, but when I add the objects via `DbSet.Add`, it threw an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Orders_Code". The conflict occurred in database "Store", table "dbo.OrderCode", column 'Id'.

It looks EFCore will try to add this field in insert statement even it is not set, so is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use int? for Code in your model. Default value for int is 0 so entity framework sets that for Code field.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Code { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    ... // other fields
}
```

Comment: But then everywhere in the code that uses this field need to updated to foo.Value, and also check with foo.HasValue. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

EF Core includes all properties in the INSERT statement by default, even if they're not explicitly set. To fix this, you have a couple of options:

1. Make the `Code` property nullable in the `Order` class:

```cs
public int? Code { get; set; }
```

2. Make the relationship between `Order` and `OrderCode` optional:

```cs
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Code { get; set; } // Make Code nullable

    [ForeignKey("Code")]
    public OrderCode OrderCode { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    // Other fields
}
```

By adding the `[ForeignKey("Code")]` attribute to the `OrderCode` navigation property, you let EF Core know that the relationship is optional. This way, EF Core won't try to insert a null value for the foreign key column.

3. If you're looking for an alternative that avoids modifying the code everywhere, you can consider using a default value for the `Code` property instead of making it nullable. By doing this, you can assign a default value to the `Code` property when it is not explicitly set, ensuring it doesn't violate the foreign key constraint. Here's an example:

```cs
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; } = 0; // Set a default value (e.g., 0)

    [ForeignKey("Code")]
    public OrderCode OrderCode { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    // Other fields
}
```

By using this approach, you won't need to modify the code everywhere to handle nullable properties. However, do keep in mind that this approach assumes 0 is a valid value in your `OrderCode` table, and it may not be suitable for all scenarios.